# How can i fix Crash in QuartzCore CA::Layer::sublayers()

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

Some of our app users are getting these crashes and I'm unable to reproduce this on my end.
Here's the stacktrace i got from crashlytics. I'm finding it difficult to understand this.
Can you please help in providing some direction where things might be going wrong.

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  QuartzCore                     0x5d340 CA::Layer::sublayers() + 4
1  UIKitCore                      0x40d84 __88-[UIView(Internal) _performUpdatesForPossibleChangesOfIdiom:orScreen:traverseHierarchy:]_block_invoke + 116
2  UIKitCore                      0x40de8 __88-[UIView(Internal) _performUpdatesForPossibleChangesOfIdiom:orScreen:traverseHierarchy:]_block_invoke + 216
3  UIKitCore                      0x40de8 __88-[UIView(Internal) _performUpdatesForPossibleChangesOfIdiom:orScreen:traverseHierarchy:]_block_invoke + 216
4  UIKitCore                      0x40de8 __88-[UIView(Internal) _performUpdatesForPossibleChangesOfIdiom:orScreen:traverseHierarchy:]_block_invoke + 216
5  UIKitCore                      0x40de8 __88-[UIView(Internal) _performUpdatesForPossibleChangesOfIdiom:orScreen:traverseHierarchy:]_block_invoke + 216
6  UIKitCore                      0x40de8 __88-[UIView(Internal) _performUpdatesForPossibleChangesOfIdiom:orScreen:traverseHierarchy:]_block_invoke + 216
7  UIKitCore                      0x40de8 __88-[UIView(Internal) _performUpdatesForPossibleChangesOfIdiom:orScreen:traverseHierarchy:]_block_invoke + 216
8  UIKitCore                      0x40de8 __88-[UIView(Internal) _performUpdatesForPossibleChangesOfIdiom:orScreen:traverseHierarchy:]_block_invoke + 216
9  UIKitCore                      0x40de8 __88-[UIView(Internal) _performUpdatesForPossibleChangesOfIdiom:orScreen:traverseHierarchy:]_block_invoke + 216
10 UIKitCore                      0x40de8 __88-[UIView(Internal) _performUpdatesForPossibleChangesOfIdiom:orScreen:traverseHierarchy:]_block_invoke + 216
11 UIKitCore                      0x40de8 __88-[UIView(Internal) _performUpdatesForPossibleChangesOfIdiom:orScreen:traverseHierarchy:]_block_invoke + 216
12 UIKitCore                      0x55104 -[UIView _performUpdatesForPossibleChangesOfIdiom:orScreen:traverseHierarchy:] + 216
13 UIKitCore                      0x49120 -[UIView _didChangeFromIdiomOnScreen:traverseHierarchy:] + 112
14 UIKitCore                      0x420578 -[UIWindow _didMoveFromScreen:toScreen:] + 684
15 UIKitCore                      0x2a2c18 -[UIWindow _didMoveFromScene:toScene:] + 296
16 UIKitCore                      0x2a29e0 -[UIWindowScene _attachWindow:] + 140
17 UIKitCore                      0x2a4b34 -[_UIScreenBasedWindowScene _attachWindow:] + 52
18 UIKitCore                      0x343790 -[UIWindow _setWindowHostingScene:] + 196
19 UIKitCore                      0x34368c -[UIWindow setWindowScene:] + 212
20 UIKitCore                      0x69e714 _UIApplicationSceneDisconnectionHandler_block_invoke_3 + 688
21 UIKitCore                      0x4a5c60 -[UIScene _invalidate] + 804
22 UIKitCore                      0x508da0 -[UIWindowScene _invalidate] + 148
23 UIKitCore                      0x47235c -[UIApplication workspace:willDestroyScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 180
24 UIKitCore                      0x46053c -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:willInvalidateWithEvent:completion:] + 288
25 FrontBoardServices             0x1c950 -[FBSScene _callOutQueue_agent_willDestroyWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 236
26 FrontBoardServices             0x20f4c __84-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient _queue_invalidateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke_2 + 120
27 FrontBoardServices             0x7120 -[FBSWorkspace _calloutQueue_executeCalloutFromSource:withBlock:] + 168
28 FrontBoardServices             0x1b5cc __84-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient _queue_invalidateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 292
29 libdispatch.dylib              0x3eac _dispatch_client_callout + 20
30 libdispatch.dylib              0x791c _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 264
31 FrontBoardServices             0x1124c __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 52
32 FrontBoardServices             0x10de8 -[FBSSerialQueue _targetQueue_performNextIfPossible] + 220
33 FrontBoardServices             0x13694 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 28
34 CoreFoundation                 0xd3128 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 28
35 CoreFoundation                 0xdf7b4 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 176
36 CoreFoundation                 0x645e8 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 244
37 CoreFoundation                 0x7a0d4 __CFRunLoopRun + 828
38 CoreFoundation                 0x7f3ec CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612
39 GraphicsServices               0x135c GSEventRunModal + 164
40 UIKitCore                      0x39cf58 -[UIApplication _run] + 888
41 UIKitCore                      0x39cbbc UIApplicationMain + 340
42 myApp-ios                     0xae7c main + 24 (AppDelegate.swift:24)
43 ???                            0x1dd91cdec (Missing)
```

Comment: This happens only when i kill the app and reopen it quickly.

Comment: did you find the reason?

Comment: Yes, i had modified the root view layers a bit which resulted in this